# Why subshell command doesn't work with echo when piped via xargs?

Tags: bash, xargs

When I use piped xargs with subshell for `echo` I get this

```sh
user@DESKTOP-P560BV8:~/tmp/t$ echo ./foo/bar.jpg | xargs -I{} echo "$(basename {})"
./foo/bar.jpg
```

However, this works

```sh
user@DESKTOP-P560BV8:~/tmp/t$ echo ./foo/bar.jpg | xargs -I{} basename {}
bar.jpg
```

and if I inline the parameter value

```sh
user@DESKTOP-P560BV8:~/tmp/t$ echo "$(basename ./foo/bar.jpg)"
bar.jpg
```

I don't understand why is it behaves like that? I need `xargs` to execute on each line of the text separately, so `-0` parameter is not an option

Comment: The command substitution is expanded before `xargs` ever runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute `basename` in a subshell then use it this way:

```sh
echo './foo/bar.jpg' |
xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo "$(basename "$1")"' _ '{}'

bar.jpg
```

We are passing dummy value `_` as `$0` for subshell and placeholder  `{}` will be passed to subshell as `$1`

Comment: Using this technique, we can even eliminate calling basename, and provide more args to the shell process: `... | xargs sh -c 'for arg; do echo "${arg##*/}"; done' _` -- this reduces the number of process that need to be spawned